# pentaho divide 2 columns each other from different csv

Tags: csv, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

In pentaho,I have 2 csv file and I need to divide columns with each other and write results into new TABLE.

1.csv

| No | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 14 |
| 2 | 8 | 20 |

2.csv

| No | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 10 |

Output should be
output.csv

| No | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |

There are at least **500 rows and columns** on each csv. How can I divide each csv with each other and create new table with results ?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each column in `df1`, divide it by its corresponding column in `df2`, and add the result column to `output`:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
output = pd.DataFrame()

# `.iteritems` is used to iterate over (column name, Series) pairs.
for col_name, col_values in df.iteritems(): 
    output[col_name] = col_values / df2[col_name]

output.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a transformation and add following steps:

- Read csv1
- Read csv2

After each Read csv, add a **Select values** step renaming the columns No, A and B so there's no confusion on to which file the columns come (you could skip this, you'll just get the columns renamed when you merge both files, but you won't have control over it, or just use one Select values step and leave the column names in one of the files as is, I like adding this step for clarity when debugging information in following steps)

After the **Select values** steps, add a **Sort rows** step, ordering by the *No* column for each stream of data.

After the **Sort rows** steps, you add a unique step, **Merge join**, merging the data of both files, where the *No* column of each file has the same value.

After this step, your data will look like this:

| No1 | A1 | B1 | No2 | A2 | B2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 14 | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 20 | 2 | 4 | 10 |

So you just can add a **Calculator** step performing two operations:

- A3 = A1/A2
- B3 = B1/B2

And finally add **Text File Output** step to create your output.csv with the three columns: No1 (or No2, both columns have the same content), A3 and B3.

[image: Transformation Example]

Comment: Hi Ana, Thanks for clarification but calculator is defining only for specific column A and B. I have 400 column and 800 rows it would be impossible to define for each. How can I make loop or iterative to calculate for whole columns?

Comment: Does Metadata Injection work with the Calculator step? In that case you could make a transformation to inject to the Select values, Calculator and Text file output step the column names to perform the corresponding operations. I'm almost sure it works with the Select values, and it certainly works to inject the Text file output step the columns of the file, but I'm not so sure about the Calculator. Check the Pentaho documentation at Hitachi Vantara website to see if it would be posible.

Comment: Thanks  Ana but  unfortunately metadata injection is not working with calculator.  Do you have any other recomendation?COloumn names are hexadecimal "00:00:00X","00:00:01X","00:00:02X","00:00:03X","00:00:04X","00:00:05X","00:00:06X","00:00:07X","00:00:08X","00:00:09X","00:00:0AX","00:00:0BX"...--> goes until 400 columns . I am still not clear how to do it.

Comment: Buff, this is completely out of the box, but if the structure of the files doesn't change and you only need to create the transformation once, you could just add a pair of columns to the Calculator step and the Select values steps, just to have the structure of the metadata, and then open the transformation (inside is just an XML file) with a text editor such as Notepad++, VS Code or the like, localize the definition of the columns in the Calculator step, and add the rest of the columns with a macro or a script.

Comment: I have try to add field names as you declared in calculator step. I got an error when devide by 0. Same field name is 0 so How can I omit them ? Do you have any idea?

Comment: So to treat zero values in your division you can do multiple things depending on how you want to treat those divisions. If you just want to have the result column treated giving a NULL, in the stream processing the 2.csv file add the step *Null if* converting all number type columns to NULL when their value is 0. If you want to treat those columns in another way, you'll have to complicate your transformation or even use two transformations separating rows with division by zero from "normal" rows.