# pentaho calculator step divide by 0

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am getting an error  when I run calculator step for rows that has 0 values.Some values have 0 number. Do you know how can I omit them? or How can pentaho pass these values without doing nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered in your other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159997/pentaho-divide-2-columns-each-other-from-different-csv/68162522?noredirect=1#comment120506563_68162522), but as you have made a new thread with this new problem, I'll post my answer here again:

So to treat zero values in your division you can do multiple things depending on how you want to treat those divisions.

If you just want to have the result column treated giving a NULL, in the stream processing the csv2 file add the step *Null if* converting all number type columns to NULL when their value is 0.

If you want to treat those columns in another way, you'll have to complicate your transformation or even use two transformations separating rows with division by zero from "normal" rows.