# pentaho divide 2 column

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

As you seen in screenshots there are csv files and many columns in it. I am trying to divide columns with next column in calculator step. For example 00:00:00X divide by 00:00:01X But there is almost 700 columns.

I have tried etl metadata injection but calculator does not support so that couldn't pass the values.

How can I define whole rows in calculator step? Do you have any other idea?

[image: calculatorstep]

[image: previewdata]

[image: csvinput]

[image: transformation]

Answer (score 0):

As I said in your original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159997/pentaho-divide-2-columns-each-other-from-different-csv/68162522?noredirect=1#comment120506563_68162522), this is an out of the box solution, if you only have to treat this file this way, I would create a sample with only the first two columns, save the transformation and afterwards edit the transformation (inside is just an xml file) with a text editor such as Notepad++, Visual Studio Code or whatever you use.

Localize the part where the calculator step is defined, something like:

```
<step>
  <name>MyCalculator</name>
  <type>Calculator</type>
  ...
  <calculation>
      <field_name>e</field_name>
      <calc_type>DIVIDE</calc_type>
      <field_a>a</field_a>
      <field_b>b</field_b>
      <field_c/>
      <value_type>Number</value_type>
      <value_length>-1</value_length>
      <value_precision>-1</value_precision>
      <remove>N</remove>
      <conversion_mask/>
      <decimal_symbol/>
      <grouping_symbol/>
      <currency_symbol/>
    </calculation>
    <calculation>
    ...
    </calculation>
   ...
</step>
```

Afterwards, you get a list of your columns a reproduce with a macro all the calculations you need with that structure, and add them to the file.

If this is not a one time solution to create a unique transformation, you'll need to program a solution with a language your comfortable using or even create a transformation to simulate the metadata injection to the calculator step, in that last case you'll need to add your own java code to the transformation, and I'm not a java developer, so I can't help you there.